# Reuse same object in other methods within same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails 3.2. I have the following code:

```
# photo.rb
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :associate_current_user
  after_save :increase_user_photos_count
  after_destroy :decrease_user_photos_count

  private

  def associate_current_user
    current_user = UserSession.find.user
    self.user_id = current_user.id
  end

  def increase_user_photos_count
    current_user = UserSession.find.user
    User.increment_counter(:photos_count, current_user.id)
  end

  def decrease_user_photos_count
    current_user = UserSession.find.user
    User.decrement_counter(:photos_count, current_user.id)
  end
end
```

Before a new record is created, it searches for the `current_user`. This is alright if it's just 1 new record at a time. But if there are 100 records to be created, it's gonna search for the same `current_user` 100 times. There is definitely performance issue.

1. I don't want it to keep finding the current user every time a record is created/photos_count updated, etc.
2. After refactoring, does this affect other users who are also uploading their photos using their accounts?

**Note:** For some reasons, I can't use the `counter_cache` and `photos_controller.rb` because I am following this example: http://www.tkalin.com/blog_posts/multiple-file-upload-with-rails-3-2-paperclip-html5-and-no-javascript

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= UserSession.find.user
end
```

This will cache the value in the instance variable `@current_user` unless it's nil (first time in the request), in which case it will set it.

Comment: Can this be used in the model? How do I call the `current_user` in other method?

Comment: It's probably not something you would add to a model, since (I assume) current user is dependent upon the request context).  Add it to `application_controller.rb` and it will be available in all controllers.  Add the line `helper_method :current_user` after the `end` and it will also be available in views.  To use, just reference `current_user`, e.g. `current_user.id` -- instead of being a variable storing an object (the user instance), it's a method that returns the same thing.

Comment: I am not using any controller to create those new records, so even in `application_controller.rb`, it wouldn't help in this case.

Comment: ok, well there's nothing magic about this code -- it *will* work in a model assuming UserSession is just another model.  The names you're using are confusing -- it's a convention in Rails to reference the currently logged in user as `current_user`, and "sessions" usually refer to the special session cookies managed by browsers and accessed within Rails in the `session` object.  If you want this method available from all models, there are several ways to do this, for example create an initializer that contains the method -- many other options.